# i3 not working with xbacklight

Tags: brightness, i3-wm, xbacklight

I'm not able to decrease or increase. This is current config for the screen brightness using xbacklight:

```
 bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec xbacklight -inc 20 # increase screen brightness
 bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec xbacklight -dec 20 # decrease screen brightness
```

I also tried using [light](https://github.com/haikarainen/light) to no avail with this:

```
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec light -A 5 # increase screen brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec light -U 5 # decrease screen brightness
```

Not using these two at once, of course. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. If you need any other information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Do these commands even work in the terminal ? Have you tested them f.ex : `xbacklight -dec 20` or `light -U 5` ?

Comment: No, neither of them work.

Answer (score 0):

When using light, try adding yourself to the video group

sudo usermod -a -G video yourusername